# Update an innerHTML value with ajax and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am having this really weird problem when updating a `<p>`'s `innerHTML` value. I wanted to change it without reloading the page so I used ajax. The problem is that it seem to fail to change the `innerHTML`, I am trying to make a page that gets an ID from an `<input>` and then pass the value to a php script using ajax, but it seem I am doing something wrong with my `searchEmp()` function. More details below...

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="searchForm">
        EMPLOYEE ID: <input type="text" name='emp_id' id='emp_id'/>
        <button onclick="searchEmp()"/>Search</button>
</form>
        <br>
        NAME:<p id='empName'>A </p><br>
        POSITION:<p id='empPos'>B </p>

<script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
            function searchEmp() {

                var emp_id = document.getElementById('emp_id').value;
                var query = "?emp_id=" + emp_id;
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

                    if(this.readyState == 4) {
                       jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                       document.getElementById('empName').innerHTML = jsonResponse.empName;
                       document.getElementById('empPos').innerHTML = jsonResponse.empPosition;

                    }
                }

                xhr.open("GET", "retrieve_data.php" +query, true);

                xhr.send();

            }
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

I thought my PHP script was the problem at first, but I guess I am wrong-- I tried troubleshooting so I changed my `searchEmp()` in to...

```
<script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
            function searchEmp() {

                var emp_id = document.getElementById('emp_id').value;
                var query = "?emp_id=" + emp_id;
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

                    if(this.readyState == 4) {

                        alert("readystate: "+xhr.readyState);
                        alert("status: "+xhr.status);
                        document.getElementById('empName').innerHTML = "NICE!";
                        document.getElementById("empPos").innerHTML = "NICE!";

                    }
                }

                xhr.open("GET", "retrieve_data.php" +query, true);

                xhr.send();

            }
</script>
```

What I have discovered troubleshooting is that

1. The alertbox displayed readystate: 4 and Status: 200
2. Despite the fact that the readystate is indeed equals to 4, the `innerHTML` of my `<p>` did not change at all into a simple "Nice!"

How does an `xmlhttprequest` exactly behave? what is its life cycle? I have searched the internet for answers but could not find any GOOD and CLEAR answers. I am a student of web development, any insights would be much appreciated. Thank you!

retrieve_data.php:

```
<?php

$emp_id = $_GET["emp_id"];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "overtimedtr";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees where id ='".$emp_id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $result["empName"] = $row['name'];
        $result["empPosition"] = $row['position'];

    }
} else {
    $result["empName"] = '0 results.';
    $result["empPosition"] = '0 results.';
}

exit(json_encode($result));
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: You are submitting your page. Change `<button onclick="searchEmp()"/>Search</button>` to `<button type="button" onclick="searchEmp()"/>Search</button>`

Comment: A safer/better alternative is `<form name="searchForm" onsubmit="return searchEmp()">
        EMPLOYEE ID: <input type="text" name='emp_id' id='emp_id'/>
        <button type="submit"/>Search</button>
</form>` and return false or use preventDefault in the searchEmp function

Comment: @mplungjan how does changing  `type="button"` matter when using `xmlhttprequest`?

Comment: Default button handler in a form is SUBMIT. The page reloads after the alerts, resetting the text in the P

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you! now it makes sense.